# What is an EnvironmentalModifier in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

As per the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentalmodifier), an `EnvironmentalModifier` is:

> A modifier that must resolve to a concrete modifier in an environment before use.

What does this mean? Examples appreciated.

UPDATE: note that the question does not refer to the `environment` view modifier, but to the `EnvironmentalModifier` (note the -al suffix), which is a protocol for view modifiers.

Comment: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-protocols/, search for EnvironmentalModifier

Answer (score 1):

An `EnvironmentalModifier` is a `ViewModifier` that decides precisely what effect should be applied to a view by using a value from the environment.

Here is a Playground example:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ShadowModifier: ViewModifier {
  let whichShadow: ShadowSetting.Value

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    switch whichShadow {
    case .none:
      content
    case .blue:
      content
        .shadow(color: .blue, radius: 10)
    case .red:
      content
        .shadow(color: .red, radius: 10)
    }
  }
}

struct ShadowSetting: EnvironmentKey {
  enum Value {
    case none
    case blue
    case red
  }

  static var defaultValue = Value.none
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
  var shadowSetting: ShadowSetting.Value {
    get { self[ShadowSetting.self] }
    set { self[ShadowSetting.self] = newValue }
  }
}

struct OnlyTheShadowKnows: EnvironmentalModifier {
  typealias ResolvedModifier = ShadowModifier

  func resolve(in environment: EnvironmentValues) -> ShadowModifier {
    return ShadowModifier(whichShadow: environment[keyPath: \.shadowSetting])
  }
}


extension View {
  func customModifier() -> some View {
    return self
  }
}

struct MyView : View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      HStack {
        Text("Hello")
          .modifier(OnlyTheShadowKnows())
      }
      .environment(\.shadowSetting, .blue)

      HStack {
        Text("Hello")
          .modifier(OnlyTheShadowKnows())
      }
      .environment(\.shadowSetting, .red)

    }.frame(width: 320, height: 240)
  }
}

let hosted = MyView()
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: hosted)
```

In the example the `ShadowModifier` is a view modifier that can add a red shadow or a blue shadow to a view depending on how its constructed.

`ShadowSetting` is a custom environment value that provides options for a shadow color. The `EnvironmentValues` are extended to hold a `ShadowSetting`.

`OnlyTheShadowKnows` is an `EnvironmentalModifier`.  It examines the `ShadowSetting` in the current environment and "resolves" it to the correct `ShadowModifer` to apply based on the value of the environment's `shadowSetting`.

`MyView` has two little view hierarchies with different `shadowSettings` in their environment.  Each `Text` label applies the `OnlyTheShadowKnows` modifier and that resolves to the correct shadow.

The last bit puts `MyView` on the screen.